# Particular website times out in all browsers

Tags: networking, dns

I can't access the website [eslint.org](http://eslint.org/) from my personal Macbook Pro. I know the site is up and I can access it from other devices, but when I try to open it on my computer the browser times out and says that it can't find the DNS address for the site. Regardless of browser. I have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: We'll need more info... OS? Can you `ping` the site by name? How about by IP address? Have you tried flushing your DNS cache?

Comment: OS is OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. I cannot ping the site: `ping: cannot resolve eslint.org: Unknown host`. I can ping it by IP adress though. I've flushed my cache, doesn't help.

Comment: @durrrutti - Change your DNS servers then repeat the tests.

Comment: Chaning DNS server fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing my DNS server to 8.8.8.8 (as per [this guide](http://osxdaily.com/2015/12/05/change-dns-server-settings-mac-os-x/)) the issue resolved itself.